# LibGDX 3d follow a object or point

Tags: java, algorithm, 3d, path, libgdx

I have troubles with rotation object to direction position.

I need rotate ModelInstance(example code) to point or ModelIstance.

But when I use a setToLookAt it always reset my transform. I need something like lookAt not set it, just looking to direction.

How can I do it please?

Variables:

```
private Vector3 position;
private ArrayList<Vector3> path;
private int currentWaypointId = 0;
private Vector3 direction = new Vector3();
private Vector3 tmpV2 = new Vector3(), tmpV1 = new Vector3();
private float speed;
```

Update method:

```
public void update(float delta){
    if(path != null){
        transform.getTranslation(tmpV2);
        tmpV1 = path.get(currentWaypointId).cpy();

         if (tmpV1.dst(tmpV2) < 2){
             currentWaypointId++;
             if (currentWaypointId >= path.size()) currentWaypointId = 0;
             tmpV1 = path.get(currentWaypointId).cpy();
         }

         direction = (tmpV1).sub(tmpV2).nor();

         transform.translate(direction.scl(speed*delta));
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

Thanks for answer

Comment: does it follow the path correctly? You don't ever set its rotation, therefore it cannot be rotated to its direction

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Path-interface-%26-Splines. The derivativeAt method can be used to rotate the direction.

Comment: @Springrbua I'm moving object without rotation.

Comment: @Xoppa I'm sorry, I sad it wrong. I rewrited a question.

Comment: You can use `setToRotation(Vector3 direction, Vector3 face)`, where the direction is the `direction` you want to look and `face` is the face, which should look in this `direction`.

Comment: I need something like `transform.setToRotation(direction, face).translate(direction.scl(speed*delta));`
this is not working do you know working equivalent?
Becouse setToRotation reset position.